# Android Button not registering in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I am working with fragments and I am coming across a weird issue, and is that my buttons are not working inside my oncreateview in a fragment i am setting.

```html
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {


        val sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(requireContext(), 0, Intent(SENT), 0)
        val delivered = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(requireContext(),0, Intent(DELIVERED), 0)



        val textContact = view?.findViewById<View>(R.id.text_contact)
        textContact?.setOnClickListener {
            checkForSmsPermission()
            Log.v("Main", "Yess")
            val sms = SmsManager.getDefault()

            sms.sendTextMessage("5554",null, "I need help", sentPI, delivered)

        }
        
}
```

I am also logging it, but I get no response at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You onCreateView() should be like below

```
 override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val root = inflater.inflate( R.layout.your_fragment_layout, container, false)

    val sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(requireContext(), 0, Intent(SENT), 0)
    val delivered = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(requireContext(),0, Intent(DELIVERED), 0)

    val textContact = root.findViewById<View>(R.id.text_contact)
    textContact?.setOnClickListener {
        checkForSmsPermission()
        Log.v("Main", "Yess")
        val sms = SmsManager.getDefault()

        sms.sendTextMessage("5554",null, "I need help", sentPI, delivered)

    }
        return root
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! Could you explain why we set a root view? I am new to fragments and android development in general

Comment: Actually fragment should not function without activity, so we should create fragment and add it to activity. And your fragment view will add to activity view

Comment: @RajasekaranM @ZubirAmjad this may work, but per documentation you should not use ```findViewById``` before ```onViewCreated``` was invoked. 

I would suggest you override it and move the view initialization code there. You can either keep the ```root``` reference or use the ```getView``` function the fragments offer.